# Supervisord can't control celery workers, how to do the same using Monit

Tags: django, celery, supervisord, monit, celerybeat

Supervisord cant controll my celery services(workers, flower, django and celerybeat).
When system startup, I can see all processes running successfully, if 1 of processes fail and supervisor does not restart it, when I reload or restart supervisord, everything under supervisord fails and cant be re-launched.

I have tried to move my celery services under monit. 
I created celery services in `/etc/init.d/` and services run perfectly, I can start/stop them without problems, then I set up monit scripts for all of them.

The problem is that monit is unable to start my celery-workers services, it is able to start/stop "django", "flower" and "celerybeat" without problems, but workers services under `init.d` are unable to be started by monit.

Could you please sugest me any idea how to fix this?
Why other services can be managed by monit without problems, but workers not?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Did you check `supervisord` log file ?

Comment: Please include config files and code to allow people to help you.

Comment: ```2019-01-22 14:59:40,041 INFO exited: worker0 (exit status 1; not expected)

2019-01-22 14:59:40,253 INFO gave up: worker0 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

2019-01-22 14:59:40,274 INFO exited: worker1 (exit status 1; not expected)

2019-01-22 14:59:41,275 INFO gave up: worker1 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly```